# Adding labels from another variable to a single bar in a barchart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add a string variable to my graph but i don't know how to have it inside the bar.
My string variable is called city.

```
ax.barh(df['date'].values, df['cases'].values, color= '#49cff3')
ax.text(0, 1.06, 'Number of Cases', transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='#777777')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.text(0, 1.15, 'Total Number of cases',
        transform=ax.transAxes, size=24, weight=600, ha='left', va='top')
plt.yticks()
plt.box(False)
```

here is my output

[image]

Many thanks in advance

edit: i tried adding  @JohanC 's solution and got the following output:
[image]

Comment: `ax.set_yticks(range(len(df)))`; `ax.set_yticklabels(df['city'])`

Comment: i tried this solution and it yielded a empty chart with the cities all bundled in the corner; i added the picture to the original question. appreciating your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set dates as the y-axis, `ax.set_yticks(range(len(df)))` followed by  `ax.set_yticklabels(df['city'])` would work just fine.

But a more recommended way is to directly use the cities for the y-axis. Tick marks can be made of length zero, so they keep signalling the position for the tick labels without the marks being visible.

If you want dates as the y-axis, and put the labels inside the bars, you could just place the text via a loop. But it doesn't make too much sense to use the date as the y-axis without showing them.

To invert the y-axis, with the smallest (or first) values at the top, use `ax.invert_yaxis()`.

As the post didn't include test data, the example below starts with creating some random data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=10),
                   'cases': np.random.randint(80, 200, 10),
                   'city': [f'City {i}' for i in range(1, 11)]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(df['date'], df['cases'], color='#49cff3')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)
# ax.set_yticks([]) # this would make the both the tick marks and their labels disappear
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    ax.text(0, row.date, ' '+row.city, ha='left', va='center', color='crimson')
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.box(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: i am aware i did make them invisible on purpose since what i wanted is for the data of the dates to be on the y axis and the cities to be displayed inside the bar because i want to know on April 3rd the most cases were in NewYork